# matrix differentiation of lp norm

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, normed-spaces, matrix-calculus, least-squares

I'm trying to figure out what is the gradient [matrix differentiation] of the lp norm. I saw a few other posts regarding the specific case when for example when p=2 so I think that:

$$\frac{\partial d}{\partial x} ||Ax - b||_2  = A$$

but what about for different arbitrary values of p? In that case, what is$\frac{\partial d}{\partial x} ||Ax - b||_p $, where subscript _p means lp-norm?

Comment: Welcome to math.exchange @dektorpan.

Comment: Note that in least squares L2 norm SQUARED is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, you can write the definition of a p norm and then try to compute the partial derivative.
$\| \boldsymbol{\mathrm{x}}\|_p = (|x_1|^p + |x_2|^p + \dots + |x_n|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}$

For computing a partial derivative with respect to one variable, you assume all the rest of variables are constants and then compute a real derivative wrt the single variable in consideration.

$$\frac{\partial \| \boldsymbol{\mathrm{x}}\|_p }{\partial x_i}=  (|x_1|^p + |x_2|^p + \dots + |x_n|^p)^ {1/p-1}*|x_i|^{p-1} * sign(x_i)$$
(Need to check the math here to make sure there are no typos)

You may be able to simplify and combine your partials to come up with a matrix\vector form for the gradient matrix\vector.

When there are functions inside the norm, you can use matrix chain rule for the rest of the computation.
[Matrixcookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf) could be useful here.

Note that some norm are not differentiable in every point. Eg. L1 norm is not differentiable at the zero vector.

*Typo in the derivative is fixed

Comment: is 1st term  exponent 1- 1/p or 1/p - 1?

Comment: It should be 1/p -1. Fixed.

Comment: You might find page 8 here useful too.  http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes1.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Define two new variables
$$\eqalign{
 M &= (AX-B) &\implies &dM=A\,dX \cr
 C &= {\rm abs}(M) &\implies &C\odot C=M\odot M \cr
   &\,&\,&C\odot dC=M\odot dM \cr
}$$
where we used $\odot$ denote the elementwise/Hadamard product.

Let's also define Hadamard powers of a matrix in the obvious way, i.e. $M^{\odot 3} = M\odot M\odot M$. Finally, let's use a colon to denote the trace/Frobenius product, i.e. 
$\,\,A:X={\rm tr}(A^TX)$.

Now we can express the norm in a form which will allow us to find its differential and gradient 
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \|M\|_p \cr
\phi^p &= \|M\|_p^p = 1:C^{\odot p} \cr
d\phi^p
 &= 1:pC^{\odot(p-1)}\odot dC \cr
 &= pC^{\odot(p-2)}: C\odot dC \cr
p\phi^{p-1}d\phi &= pC^{\odot(p-2)}: M\odot dM \cr
\cr
d\phi &= \phi^{1-p} C^{\odot(p-2)}\odot M: dM \cr
 &= \phi^{1-p} C^{\odot(p-2)}\odot M: A\,dX \cr
 &= \phi^{1-p} A^T\Big(C^{\odot(p-2)}\odot M\Big) : dX \cr
\cr
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial X}
 &= \phi^{1-p} A^T\Big(M\odot C^{\odot(p-2)}\Big) \cr
 &= \phi^{1-p} A^T\Big((AX-B)\odot ({\rm abs}(AX-B))^{\odot(p-2)}\Big) \cr
}$$
Be careful when $p<1$ and components of $M\rightarrow 0$.

Note that when $p=2$ the gradient reduces to
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial X}
 &= \phi^{-1} A^T(AX-B) \cr
}$$
which is a bit different than what you had assumed.